# Cocos2D MenuLevel how to lock, unlock

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I am using MenuLevel in my game for loading levels.. http://www.prioregroup.com/iphone/menulevel.aspx

At the moment, whether a level is locked or not, it's loading.. If it's locked, it should not be loading.. How can I do that? Thanks..

// create menu item

```
    [menu createMenuItemLevel:1 position:ccp(x, size.height / 2) life:0 locked:NO];  





- (void)menuLevel:(MenuLevel *)menuLevel buttonSelected:(id)source
{
    CCMenuItem *item = (CCMenuItem*)source;
    NSString *msg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You have pressed the button # %d", item.tag]; // retrieve level number.. 
            NSLog(@"MenuLevel Sample %@", msg);


// What I want is something like..  if (item.locked == YES) do something

}
```

Comment: I have updated my answer. Try that..

Comment: Did you try my code?? Is it working..??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the userData property. In your `MenuLevel.m` file add the following lines in

```
- (CCMenuItem*)createMenuItemLevel:(NSInteger)level 
                          position:(CGPoint)position 
                              life:(NSInteger)life 
                            locked:(BOOL)locked
                            target:(id)target
                          selector:(SEL)selector
```

method.

```
if (locked)
{
    item.userData = @"locked";
}
else
{
    item.userData = @"notLocked";
}
```

And in your `buttonSelected:` method check that userData as given below:

```
NSString *lockString = (NSString *)item.userData;
if ([lockString isEqualToString:@"locked"])
{
    // Locked level
}
else
{
    // Unlocked
}
```

Comment: Actually I wanna distinguish which button is locked or unlocked.. i will update my question shortly..